# Creating PDF file with large data by springboot with jasper report

Tags: spring-boot, itext, jasper-reports

I create PDF file with large data (approximate 100,000 records) after starting My service, it is working properly

[image]

But 2 days pass or 1 week pass there are somethings wrong on PDF report like image below. What is the problem for this and how to fix it.

[image]

I use springboot version 2.7.11 and jasper version 6.20.0 running on docker and kubernates

I would like to generate report PDF with large data properly like image below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpx4J.png)

Comment: Without any code it is difficult to tell. Also which version of iText are you using? There are too many details missing to efficiently help you.